# Defining Variables in If and Else, java

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with the following section of code, and have narrowed it down quite a bit, but need an expert eye to explain why it breaks as it does.

Code below is part of a graph theory problem, nodes (Astronauts) are given with Edges (Pairings), ad the resulting graph has multiple unconnected subgraphs. The problem I'm solving doesn't require unconnected Nodes to be created as objects.

I am creating individual Nodes by iterating through each pairing of names (ints) provided in the input. Then feeding those node objects into a constructor for the Edge objects.
To ensure that I don't create duplicates of the same Nodes, I have created a list to check the node's name (int) hasn't already been given.
If the node's name hasn't been given already, a new node is created as variable A or B. 
If it's name HAS been given already, the loop finds and assigns the existing node object to the placeholder variables A or B.

I am getting a compile time error (working in the Hackerrank.com editor) for the 3rd to last line in the code below:

"error: cannot find symbol
 Pairing P = new Pairing(A,B);
                                    ^
 symbol:   variable A"
(This error occurs identically for both variables A & B, only one error message shown here)
I know that the if (){} else {} section which declares/selects variables A & B has introduced this error, but my code requires the if/else check to be present.

Can someone explain why the code below throws this error, or suggest alternative methods to get around the problem? Many thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //...
    ArrayList<Pairing> allPairings = new ArrayList<>(0);
    ArrayList<Astronaut> allAstronauts = new ArrayList<>(0);
    ArrayList<Integer> givenInts = new ArrayList<>(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < I; i++) {
        temp = bfr.readLine().split(" ");
        int a = Integer.parseInt(temp[0]);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(temp[1]);

        // Check values against list to see if they have been given before
        if (!(givenInts.contains(a))) {
            Astronaut A = new Astronaut(a);
            allAstronauts.add(A);
        } else {
            // Check all current astronauts for same name
            for (int t = 0; t < allAstronauts.size(); t++) {
                if (allAstronauts.get(t).getName() == a) {
                    Astronaut A = allAstronauts.get(t);
                }
            }
        }

        if (!(givenInts.contains(b))) {
            Astronaut B = new Astronaut(b);
            allAstronauts.add(B);
        } else {
            // Check all current astronauts for same name
            for (int r = 0; r < allAstronauts.size(); r++) {
                if (allAstronauts.get(r).getName() == b) {
                    Astronaut B = allAstronauts.get(r);
                }
            }
        }

        givenInts.add(a);
        givenInts.add(b);

        Pairing P = new Pairing(A,B);
        allPairings.add(P);
    }
```

Comment: You need to declare first, it in the scope where you need it.

Comment: Why are you redefining variables?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I can see I've caused a problem there by defining variables in different sections, but I'm not sure I understand why it's a problem. 
The code worked perfectly fine looping back over the same "Astronaut A = new Astronaut(input); multiple times, and only failed when it was enclosed in an if/else statement :-/

Comment: The `if / else` block is a new scope. Declaring a variable within that scope limits its accessibility to that scope.

Comment: That's great, Thanks @dave

Comment: @EdwardLangdon Feel free to accept my answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of both `A` and `B` is limited to the blocks they are created in. So they are both out of scope by the time you get to your second last line (`Pairing P = new Pairing(A,B);`). Hence they are not available to be used there.

It's a little hard to tell, but I think you want to declare `A` and `B` near the top of your `for` loop and remove any further declarations.

Sample code (with some irrelevant bits omitted)

```
for (int i = 0; i < I; i++) {
    Astronaut A, B;
    if (!(givenInts.contains(a))) {
        A = new Astronaut(a);
        allAstronauts.add(A);
    } else {
        //check all current astronauts for same name
        for (int t = 0; t < allAstronauts.size(); t++) {
            if (allAstronauts.get(t).getName().equals(a)) {
                A = allAstronauts.get(t);
            }
        }
    }
    if (!(givenInts.contains(b))) {
         B = new Astronaut(b);
         allAstronauts.add(B);
    } else {
        //check all current astronauts for same name
        for (int r = 0; r < allAstronauts.size(); r++) {
            if (allAstronauts.get(r).getName().equals(b)) {
                B = allAstronauts.get(r);
            }
        }
    }
    Pairing P = new Pairing(A,B);
```

You may get a warning about `A` or `B` being unassigned. If so, perhaps set them to `null` and only create the `Pairing` if they are both non-null.

Note: I also changed your string comparisons from `== b` to `.equals(b)`.